# PHP get variable from shell script

Tags: php, shell-exec

How can php get variable from shell script.
I have: `shell_exec('php /var/www/html/test/kobi.php $param1');`
And i want to recieved `$parm1 in kobi.php` 
I tried to do it with: `$imsi=$argv[1];`
but it doesn't work.
can someone explain what's wrong?
How should i do that correct?

Comment: it contains nothing ...., because the script executing inside of `shell_exec` is running in a separate thread, and `$argv` is for this thread.  I use the term thread loosely.  Instance of PHP is probably more "proper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong function try  `exec` instead

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

```
   $param1 = escapeshellarg( $param1 );
   exec('php /var/www/html/test/kobi.php $param1', $output );
```

And use this too.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Otherwise someone take over your server maybee...

***UPDATE***

```
'php /var/www/html/test/kobi.php $param1'
```

Is string literal, so your input is `$param1` literally, not the value of it.  By the way.  You would use `"` double quotes for variable interpolation.

Comment: Still doesnt work.
By echo $output Im getting an empty array

Comment: `echo` literally? because `print_r()` `var_export()`, `var_dump()` are for arrays, you can't echo an array.

Comment: sorry i meant to print_r() ofcours.
what should i do??

Comment: Then run your script on the command line and see if it outputs anything, chances are it's not.

Comment: @K.D - check you quotes `'` vs `"`

Comment: Also on windows the php.exe should be configured in the PATH environmental variable, otherwise you  have to use the full path to the php executable.

Comment: Yes it looks like " solved it, thank you!!
but now i facing a problem to pass an array.
im passing an array and when i prin it by print_r($arr) im getting "array".
whats wrong now?

Comment: can someone help me with that?

Comment: you cant pass an array into a shell script, only text.....

Comment: that said, you can convert the array to Json, or a CSV, and pass that in, then convert it back.

Comment: Ok, i solved it by appending array to string (with foreach loop) and passing it as a string, and after that bring it back to an array with explode.

Comment: can you accept the answer then?

Comment: Yes, i did so. Thank you